# serializing a hashtable to a file on android

Tags: android, serialization, hashtable

So I'm pretty new to the serialization scene and I don't know if it's possible to serialize a hashtable and then save it to a file... but This is what I've tried so far.. For some reason it goes to my catch portion of code instead of executing the Try blocks ?

```
public void addDataIntoFlashCardFile(Context context, Hashtable<Integer, ArrayList<Deck>> data) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(
                    FLASHCARDS_FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE
                            | Context.MODE_APPEND);
            ObjectOutputStream osw = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            osw.writeObject(data);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // catch errors opening file
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(context, "calles", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
```

Here I try to read it from a file (which won't work because it won't write to the file in the first place)

```
try {

            Hashtable<Integer, ArrayList<Deck>> temp = new Hashtable<Integer, ArrayList<Deck>>();
            FileInputStream myIn = context.openFileInput(FLASHCARDS_FILENAME);
            ObjectInputStream IS = new ObjectInputStream(myIn);
            Toast.makeText(context, "here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {

                temp = (Hashtable<Integer, ArrayList<Deck>>)IS.readObject();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            IS.close();

            //testing purposes
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
                for (int p = 0; p < temp.get(i).size(); p++) {
                    for (int q = 0; q < temp.get(i).get(p).getDeck().size(); q++) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, temp.get(i).get(p).getDeck().get(q).getQuestion(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If it goes to the catch block, then it prints a stack trace to the logcat. please attach it

Comment: for some reason in logCat it's saying that my "Deck" object isn't serializable. I get a java.io.NotSerializableException in logcat every time I run it. I've made my deck class serializable though..

Comment: What fields does `Deck` contains? Serializing is recursive, if any of the fields inside `Deck` or its fields isn't serializable, it would throw that exception.
But it would really help if you'd post the logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use a JSONObject.

Step 1: Create your JSONObject:

```
JSONObject myAwesomeObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray myAwesomeArray = new JSONArray();
```

Step 2: Iterate through your HashMap and add it to your JSONObject

```
for (Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Deck>> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    ArrayList<Deck> decks = temp.get(entry);
    JSONObject JSONDeck = new JSONObject();
    for (Deck deck : decks){
        JSONDeck.add("deck", deck.getWhateverDataDeckContains());
    }
    myAwesomeArray.add("deck", JSONDeck);
}
myAwesomeObject.add("deck_collection", myAwesomeArray);
```

Step 3: get a String containing your table:

```
String myAwesomeContents = myAwesomeObject.toString();
```

Step 4: Insert it into a file as plain text.

To deserialize it, you just iterate through your JSONObject and fill a new table.

Step 1: Get the string back from your file.

Step 2: Create a new instance of JSONObject containing that string:

```
JSONObject deserialized = new JSONObject(stringContainingYourDataInJSON);
```

Step 3: Get your simple data back:

```
ArrayList<Deck> decksArray = new ArrayList<Deck>();
JSONArray decks = deserialized.getJSONArray("deck_collection");
for (int i=0; i<decks.length(); i++){
    JSONObject deck = decks.get(i);
    String name = deck.getString("name");
    int length = deck.getInt("length");
    // etc
    Deck deckPojo = new Deck();
    deckPojo.setWhatever(whateverParamsYouWantToSet);
    decksArray.add(deckPojo);
 }
```

Comment: I've been playing around with this, and I'm pretty sure I got it to serialize to a file. I'm using the Gson library so all I have to do to serialize my hashtable is to convert it to a Json string and put it in the file. The problem I'm getting now is how can I read it back... Deserialize if you will.

Comment: Just create a JSONObject passing the string in your file and it will be deserialized.

Comment: Note that you will have to use try {} catch(JSONException ex){} because JSONObject is done that way. I'd actually prefer it to send RuntimeExceptions, but...

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining everything! I was a little lost on the deserialization :).

Comment: You're welcome, StackOverflow is all about learning new things ;-)

Comment: RuntimeException has a Throwable constructor. So you can append your JSONException in it